# Issues downloading software to Ubuntu after install

Tags: software-installation

I have many questions and issues, and not one of them has been solved by searching google and previous forum posts. I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. Specifically, I have the Microsoft Surface Pro 5th Generation in case it's important. I was able to install Ubuntu without issue, but now that I have it, I am unable to install and/or run most programs. Every time I try to run a command in the terminal, I get a different error. Every time I try to fix that error, I find more commands that come with more errors. I was hoping that this was related to a part of setup that I missed (I didn't follow a guide or anything, I only know what Ubuntu directly told me.), but after finding a video that explains things that should be setup immediately, it said to open "software and updates." This worked, but the "canonical partners" checkbox isn't there. Instead, the "other software" tab just has remnants of programs that I tried to install, but didn't work. Is the canonical partners thing important? Are there any other major settings, software, or configurations that I might be missing? I tried to just go back to Windows 10, but I replaced it with Ubuntu completely and the USB drive that I used to install Ubuntu is unable to hold one of the files from the Windows 10 ISO. Any help would be appreciated. EDIT: The first issue is that I am unable to install Zoom. I absolutely need Zoom because I have online classes that are hosted there. It isn't in the Ubuntu Software application, so I went to the Zoom website and they have a Linux version. They say that I should first install a graphical installer using this: "sudo apt install gdebi" I did that and it seems to have worked, but the .deb file that Zoom told me to download doesn't run when I double-click it. Instead, it opens like a zip file. Zoom says that it should automatically be opened by the graphical installer when I double-click it. Is there another way to run it through the graphical installer? Should I be using something other than the graphical installer?

Comment: We need to focus. Your question is many question lumped together and says nothing about any. For starters software should preferably be installed from the Ubuntu repositories or SNAP (both available at the Ubuntu Software tool). No, "partners" isn't needed. Do NOT follow old tutorials that likely aren't applicable to your release, when in doubt ASK first.

Comment: Okay, I added more specific information about one of the issues.

Comment: (...) Those aren't really "remnants" but merely 3rd party repos (PPAs) that you added by following obsolete tutorials. You can remove everything there except those necessary for updating any extraneous software that you SUCCESSFULLY installed. Anything else just delete.

Comment: When searching Ubuntu Software, it doesn't show up. Do I need to change a setting within the application to see "SNAP"?

Comment: No, you don't. FIRST make sure your system is fully updated - you can use the Updates tool for that - then, at Ubuntu Software, search for "Zoom" and SCROLL down until you find "Zoom client".

Comment: Snap has an update available, so I imagine that's the issue. The problem is that it won't download the update while Ubuntu Software is running, but Ubuntu Software is where I'm downloading it, so it needs to be open. How do I download the update?

Comment: I see no mention made of what Ubuntu product you installed; Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop?  The mention of zoom could imply a desktop system with GUI, but rather than make us guess - why not be specific and tell us. What release are you using?  Sure we can answer with *snap* packages that work on all, but these may not be what's best for you, so you'll do best telling us what product, what release etc..   Using white space in your question would also make it easier to read; and stick to a single question per question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and official way to install zoom on Ubuntu is to get it from the GUI software center.  Or you can simply run:

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

Comment: This seems to be working, thank you. Should I make separate posts for my other questions, or ask them here?

Comment: If you have more questions ask them separately. Don't combine multiple questions into a single question.  Please before asking again, I suggest you read [How to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask), the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour), and this [meta topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15152) on writing questions effectively so that it won't earn you negative feedback.